# Edit a function in Python IDLE

Tags: python, function

What are the ways to edit a function defined in the environment of Python IDLE (or console)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: no.  Long answer: If you have readline support enabled, you can use the up-arrow to "redefine" it line-by-line.

Comment: That is deadly inconvenient to use command history, because when you modify a function few times, you don't really know which one it is that is defined in the environment. Is there a way to print environment function code?

Comment: All names are unique within the global namespace of the interactive interpreter used by IDLE, so you should know that the last one defined in your environment is the one that is defined.  Can you clarify what you mean about a away to print environment function code?  Do you mean the Python source code?

Comment: Sorry, no. There isn't a way to print the actual source code. At least not one that I know of.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for a way to do this myself and I'm saddened that it isn't possible but I'll share a quick workaround that I'm using.

Instead of defining the `myFunction()` in the console I define it in a file `myFile.py`. In the console I then import:

```
import myFile
from imp import reload
```

I then make a pointer to my function (in case of long filenames), like so:

```
def pMyFunction():
  return myFile.myFunction()
```

Whenever I want to amend myFunction, I do it in myFile.py and then reload the module:

```
reload(myFile)
```

Nothing too fancy but it's helping me get by.

Answer (score 2):

You can beef up Python REPL quite a bit, even [calling your favorite editor](https://web.archive.org/web/20120418174731/http://sontek.net/tips-and-tricks-for-the-python-interpreter) from it. If you're using a terminal with a mouse support (as usual in X) or screen, you just scroll up to the last function definition, copy the source, call the editor and paste to it. Edit to taste, execute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inspect module to get the current source code and then redefine the function:

```
from inspect import getsource

def helloworld():
    print('Hello, World!')

print(getsource(helloworld))
```

You could even use python string methods to change it and then use `exec` to redefine the function. However, I would consider this bad style.

```
from inspect import getsource


def helloworld():
    print('Hello, World!')

old = getsource(helloworld)
new = old.replace('Hello', 'Cheers')
exec(new)
helloworld()
```

Comment: Oh yeah I noticed but even with the right import gives an error: `OSError: could not get source code`

Comment: This example? Or something else you are trying. The example works for python 3.7 and should for any other python 3 version.

Comment: Yes, this code. I'm running 3.7.3 on the interactive prompt. Just tried again and getting the same error.

Comment: What operating System?

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.475]

Comment: Ditto: OSError on macOS 10.13.6